# QueryOver error : Unrecognised method call in expression value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a query by QueryOver in Nhibernate3.1

```
 var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
         .Where(x => IsActive(x.PersonType) == true);

 return q.List<Person>();
```

By this method:

```
private bool IsActive(PersonType type)
{
   if(type == PersonType.Employee
      return true;
   else
      return false;
}
```

Now it has a runtime error by this message:

> Unrecognised method call in expression value

Why?

Answer (score 4):

I solved a similar problem by returning an expression tree in my predicate method instead of returning a boolean value directly. Using your example, it'd be something like this:

```
private Expression<Func<PersonType, bool>> IsActive()
{
    return (t => t == PersonType.Employee );
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Usage is simply QueryOver<Person>().Where(IsActive)
Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

Your Method IsActive is a method compiled directly to IL. The query analyzer cant dissect this method and build a query out of it. I'm not sure how you can expose an expression from a method and use it in a query with NHibernate but i'm sure google can help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just do this?

```
var q = SessionInstance.QueryOver<Person>()
         .Where(x => x.PersonType == PersonType.Employee);
```

Comment: No. I want using of Another method in this query. `IsActive` method is a simple method for my example!

Comment: Maybe you should include your more complex example then.

Comment: In the spirit of clean code, a more complex example should not be needed. IsActive is much more intention revealing than only the predicate.